# How to make react-window VariableSizeList react on count of element in the list and change list height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window

I need to create a large list component with more than 1000 items with `VariableSizeList` and the height of this list should increase until it reaches `220px`.

I tried to use `AutoSizer` but it didn't help.